# Scala Get List of last 12 months from given month

Tags: java, scala, java-time

Please note scala beginner question. 
I am trying to get list of last 12 months from selected month. But the below code gives error:
**Expression of type Unit doesn't conform to expected type List[String]**

Unsure which part needs the fix. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
 def getlistofmonths(currentmonth: String): List[String] = {
    //val currentmonth="202006"

    val monthDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMM")
    val cal: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance

    cal.setTime(monthDate.parse(currentmonth))

    for (x <- 1 until 12) {
      monthDate.format(cal.getTime).toList
      cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1)
    }

  }
```

Comment: Unless you're using ancient Java (pre 8), you shouldn't use `Calendar`, but rather API from `java.time.*`, like `LocalDate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you're using very old Java (version 7 or below) you shouldn't use `Calendar`.  It's mutable and has a better alternative `YearMonth` from `java.time`:

```
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

def getlistofmonths(currentmonth: String): List[String] = {

  val monthDate = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMM")

  val start = YearMonth.parse(currentmonth, monthDate)

  (1 to 12).map(x => start.minusMonths(x).format(monthDate)).toList

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note: As Krzysztof Atłasik suggested use this solution only if it's before Java 7 or old. And my solution explains why you need new calendar instance, as it's mutable.**

```scala
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.{Calendar}

val currentmonth = "202006"

def getlistofmonths(currentmonth: String): List[String] = {
  //val currentmonth="202006"

  (1 to 12)
    .map(e => {
      val monthDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMM")
      val cal: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance
      cal.setTime(monthDate.parse(currentmonth))
      cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -e)
      monthDate.format(cal.getTime)
    })
    .toList

}
getlistofmonths(currentmonth)
```

Since same object was getting mutated in your code, you can't use the same calendar instance. So as part of the above code, it will create a calendar instance and give you back the necessary past 12 months.

Answer (score 0):

> Expression of type Unit doesn't conform to expected type List[String]

What this means, is that you've said that your function returns a `List[String]`, but you're actually not returning anything (and thus your function actually returns `Unit`).

> Unsure which part needs the fix.

To address this error, you'll need to populate a list with your results, and then `return` it at the end of the function.

(I'm not addressing the method implementation itself as that would be a different question; but as @Krzysztof Atłasik mentions in comments, you should avoid using `java.util.Calendar` any more...)